# angular not able to call service from eventhandler

Tags: javascript, angular

inside the ngOnInit() I am initializing a event

```
if (!window.addEventListener) 
{
    this.window.attachEvent('onmessage', this.eventHandler.bind(null, this.router));
} 
else 
{
    window.addEventListener('message', this.eventHandler.bind(null, this.router), false);
}
```

and inside the eventHandler as shown below I try make a call to service but the service is not being called

```
eventHandler = function (router, e) 
{
    if (response.type === "PAGE_LOAD" && response.data.pageName === "DOC")
    {
        this.BuilderService.deleteUser(this.filter).subscribe(data => this.success(),(err) => this.handleError(err.statusText));
    }
}
```

Could you please help me fix this issue

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint into `eventHandler` to see if it's called? Is it possible that you do the assignment `eventHandler = function (router, e)` after `ngOnInit`?

Comment: the event is gettign hit and the call enters the if block 
    if (response.type === "PAGE_LOAD" && response.data.pageName === "DOC")

after that the service call is not firing
but the page navigation is working
router.navigate(['Builder/Dashboard']);

Comment: Is `this.BuilderService.deleteUser(this.filter)` called? Did you step into the function with your debugger?

Comment: nope the this.BuilderService.deleteUser(this.filter) is not called. It hits  that line of code but that call is not happening

Comment: Do you get an error in the console. What's the value of `this`?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside a function is usually defined by the function's call. So in your case you use `Function.prototype.bind` to set `this` to `null`.

`this` inside your eventHandler is null, so this.BuilderService.deleteUser === null.BuilderService.deleteUser. `deleteUser` will never be called with some error.

To fix the error to need to set the correct `this` value, which is the angular component class itself. So just change `this.eventHandler.bind(null, this.router), false)` to `this.eventHandler.bind(this, this.router), false)`

Comment: the service call is not firing but the page navigation is working router.navigate(['Builder/Dashboard']);

so what should i do to make the service call fire

no function call is allowed form inside the eventhandler

Comment: `router.navigate` works because you passed in the correct router object to eventHandler. Inside your eventhander `this` is null, but router is not. It's the actual router instance with `navigate` method in it